# AWS EC2 Linux instance shutdown automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have created an AMI EC2 Linux instance but since last few days I am facing issue with this instance. It automatically shutdown and never come up again automatically. I have to start the instance manually. Earlier it was working fine.

Can you please help me to find out the root cause of the issue and the fix for the same?

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Thanks, 
Sanjiv

Comment: Look in /var/log/messages* for evidence of shutdown request.

Comment: This is the exception I saw in /var/log/messages: init: plymouth-shutdown main process (7853) terminated with status 1
init: splash-manager main process (7848) terminated with status 1
ntpd[5205]: ntpd exiting on signal 15
init: Disconnected from system bus

Answer (score 0):

You can check [AWS CloudTrail](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/) log for any additionally activity.